# Converting SQLite Database from Android to Windows (Java)

Tags: java, android, windows, sqlite

I am trying to convert an existing Android, SQLite database to a multi-platform, SQLite database in order to create a prototype of a larger project that can be tested on Windows without relying on Android.  The existing Android classes that were being imported into Eclipse (using Java) included:

- Context
- Cursor
- SQLException
- SQLiteDatabase
- SQLiteStatement

So far, I found that SQLException in Android is very similar to the class in the java.sql library (also called SQLException).  I also downloaded and included the sqlite4java.jar file, which includes the SQLiteStatement class.  In this jar file, it also has SQLiteConnection, which represents a single connection to a SQLite database.  However, I am unable to find comparable, non-Android, classes for Cursor and Context.  Does anyone know of a solution?

The main call for Cursor is as follows:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(true, table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null, null);
```

where 'db' used to be a SQLiteDatabase.  I changed 'db' to be a SQLiteConnection, but that has no query() function, so I have run into another problem.

NOTE: I have also looked at org.tmatesoft.sqljet and org.sqlite packages, but could not find anything useful.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [SQLiteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) from Zentus. Once the project is configured according to the docs, just use standard the JDBC API.

I've also heard good things about a [derivative of Zentus's library](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) by Xerial, also called SQLiteJDBC, but I've never used it.

Comment: I actually have the sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar file in my project, but I could not find any comparable class to Cursor or Context.  It also could be that I am not understanding something fully because I have no experience with SQLite or Android.

Answer (score 0):

Download SQLite JDBC drive jar file and add to projects classpath.
create databse connection:

```
String assetsDirPath = "./src/com/tamrd/speareasynlureminder/assets/";

Connection conn = null;
String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + assetsDirPath + "test.db";

try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    if (conn != null) {
        DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
        System.out.println("The driver name is " + meta.getDriverName());
        System.out.println("A new database connection has been created.");
    }

} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now using the Connection object you can execute query:

```
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        Statement stmt = queryDb.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(strQuery);
       
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("columnName"));
    }
```